# how to choose correct notification icon android

Tags: android

I have notifications that contain an icon, how do I choose the icon with the correct density from the drawable folders? Which are the resolutions of the notification icons for each drawable folder: drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi?

Comment: [Always check the developer docs](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Comment: You don't need to do that, Android does it for you. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 2):

The Android OS will choose the correct drawable for you. So if you have the following drawables:

```
drawable-hdpi \ icon.png
drawable-ldpi \ icon.png
```

The system will pick the one that best matches the device. You can use your drawable by calling

> getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)

Answer (score 1):

You don't choose the icon yourself.  The operating system will work out which icon to use based on the screen of the phone that your app is running on (new phones with high density screens are xxhpdi, and then it goes down from there).  Infact, all of the different versions of your image should be named the same; that way you just refer to that name, and the OS will take the one from whichever folder it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Notification icon must be of **24x24 dp** as given in [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification) document.